# como colocar Rss feed numa página HTML?

Tags: html5

Observem a página de internet.

[Free RSS Widget](http://www.surfing-waves.com/feed.htm)

estou com o seguinte código;

```
<!-- start sw-rss-feed code --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
rssfeed_url = new Array(); 
rssfeed_url[0]="http://esporte.uol.com.br/ultimas/index.xml";  
rssfeed_frame_width="300"; 
rssfeed_frame_height="260"; 
rssfeed_scroll="on"; 
rssfeed_scroll_step="6"; 
rssfeed_scroll_bar="off"; 
rssfeed_target="_blank"; 
rssfeed_font_size="12"; 
rssfeed_font_face=""; 
rssfeed_border="on"; 
rssfeed_css_url=""; 
rssfeed_title="on"; 
rssfeed_title_name=""; 
rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff"; 
rssfeed_title_color="#fff"; 
rssfeed_title_bgimage=""; 
rssfeed_footer="off"; 
rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed"; 
rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff"; 
rssfeed_footer_color="#333"; 
rssfeed_footer_bgimage=""; 
rssfeed_item_title_length="50"; 
rssfeed_item_title_color="#666"; 
rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff"; 
rssfeed_item_bgimage=""; 
rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on"; 
rssfeed_item_source_icon="off"; 
rssfeed_item_date="off"; 
rssfeed_item_description="on"; 
rssfeed_item_description_length="120"; 
rssfeed_item_description_color="#666"; 
rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333"; 
rssfeed_item_description_tag="off"; 
rssfeed_no_items="0"; 
rssfeed_cache = "e90320463f8111afd3b519c711ff89e3"; 
//--> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-feed.js"></script> 
<!-- The link below helps keep this service FREE, and helps other people find the SW widget. Please be cool and keep it! Thanks. --> 
<div style="text-align:right; width:300px;">powered by <a href="http://www.surfing-waves.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank" style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px">Surfing Waves</a></div> 
<!-- end sw-rss-feed code -->
```

Como faço para conseguir visualizar essa noticias numa página HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você importar os scripts para dentro do `header` do seu HTML e a `div` dentro do `body`, segue o código de uma página HTML carregando o feed:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Titulo da página</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            rssfeed_url = new Array(); 
            rssfeed_url[0]="http://esporte.uol.com.br/ultimas/index.xml";  
            rssfeed_frame_width="300"; 
            rssfeed_frame_height="260"; 
            rssfeed_scroll="on"; 
            rssfeed_scroll_step="6"; 
            rssfeed_scroll_bar="off"; 
            rssfeed_target="_blank"; 
            rssfeed_font_size="12"; 
            rssfeed_font_face=""; 
            rssfeed_border="on"; 
            rssfeed_css_url=""; 
            rssfeed_title="on"; 
            rssfeed_title_name=""; 
            rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff"; 
            rssfeed_title_color="#fff"; 
            rssfeed_title_bgimage=""; 
            rssfeed_footer="off"; 
            rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed"; 
            rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff"; 
            rssfeed_footer_color="#333"; 
            rssfeed_footer_bgimage=""; 
            rssfeed_item_title_length="50"; 
            rssfeed_item_title_color="#666"; 
            rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff"; 
            rssfeed_item_bgimage=""; 
            rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on"; 
            rssfeed_item_source_icon="off"; 
            rssfeed_item_date="off"; 
            rssfeed_item_description="on"; 
            rssfeed_item_description_length="120"; 
            rssfeed_item_description_color="#666"; 
            rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333"; 
            rssfeed_item_description_tag="off"; 
            rssfeed_no_items="0"; 
            rssfeed_cache = "e90320463f8111afd3b519c711ff89e3"; 
        </script> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-feed.js"></script> 

    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="text-align:right; width:300px;">powered by <a href="http://www.surfing-waves.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank" style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px">Surfing Waves</a></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

No import do Script via CDN eu removi o "//" e inseri "https://" pois só assim funcionou localmente aqui, e vai funcionar em qualquer lugar também.

Comment: ele funcionou no html, mas não funcionou no angular 4, mas tudo bem.

Comment: @wladyband eu não conheço muito de Angular 4 não sei como funciona mas posso te ajudar pois utilizo ASP.NET provavelmente a estrutura é parecida, edita a pergunta com o código angular dessa tela que você adicionará o feed que eu vejo se consigo te ajudar também.